# Why Django migrations create table on non-default database when not used?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Say, I have multiple apps and one of those will use it's own database (with `sqlite3` backends). So, I write the settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'default',
         # and other settings
     }
}
    'special': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'special.sqlite3',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['special.routers.SpecialRouter', ]
```

Now, when I run:

```
./manage.py makemigrations special
./manage.py migrate
```

It didn't execute queries to `default` database. That's what it's should be. But, when I run:

```
./manage.py migrate --database=special
```

all of those models that should only exits in `postgresql` is created on my `sqlite3` database. Including `auth_permissions`, `auth_goups` and all others. Is this default behaviour or misconfigurations?

Comment: That's the default behaviour. It seems you have found database routers, which allows you to tweak that behaviour. Take a look at [`allow_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate).

Comment: Default behavior. You are actually trying to make all the migrations on special database. They won't make any effect on default database.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am not able to crate tables (execute migrations) for non-default database while keeping the django generated tables in default database.

Comment: I was able to solve it by creating auth( default) database router...  Letting comments be in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use multiple database for my django app, but when i migrated database, django migrated default apps migrations to default as well as non-default database.

I was able to solve issue for this problem using `allow_migrate` method in `router` as mentioned by [@knbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615075/knbk)

I have created **DBRouter** in myapp/routers.py to route default django apps to use default database, by adding django default apps to default_apps tuple

**myapp/routers.py**

```
class DBRouter(object):
default_apps = (
    'admin',
    'auth',
    'contenttypes',
    'sessions',
    'messages',
)

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in self.default_apps:
        return 'default'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in self.default_apps:
        return 'default'
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in self.default_apps:
        return db == 'default'
    return None
```

Add that router in settings with App router

**settings.py**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['activity_manager.routers.DBRouter', 'activity_manager.routers.AppRouter']
```